# Escape apostrophe read from <img ... alt= in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just found a bug in a line of my JQuery and I'm not sure how to handle it.

```
// Enable valid swatch images
$.each(sizes, function (index, element) {
    $("#variations img[alt='" + element + "']")
         .parent().removeClass("swatchDisabled").addClass("swatchEnabled");
});
```

The problem is in the selector for the img. There is an apostrophe in the alt attribute value. I can't change the alt value easily, yet I need to use it because it contains an important value for my code logic.

Is there a graceful way of escaping this/any apostrophe contained in this alt tag so that JQuery won't choke on it?

Comment: Try replacing (literally, use string replace) the apostrophe with a code: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: I suppose... The HTML is output from an XSLT stylesheet. Just thought it might be easier to handle this in JQuery and not worry about the HTML. I have an escape template already, just didn't think I should escape an alt attribute value. I'll give it a try and see how it works out. Thanks for the reference - nice page.

Comment: By string replace I meant the javascript function, like @Esailija used  in his answer, sorry if that was confusing xD

Comment: Ok. Yes, I kinda like handling it in JQuery better. Thanks TheZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#variations img[alt='" + element.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "']")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwEqs/

Comment: I think I like this better. :P Nice. Would you escape the alt attribute in your XSLT or just do it in your JQuery? I don't reference this selector but once in my JQuery script (I think).

Comment: @rwkiii  If the alt attribute has `'` (escaped or not) you will have to escape the query as well (since you are using `'` as delimiter for the attr value string). Here's the html escaped version and it makes no difference http://jsfiddle.net/UwEqs/1/

Comment: I see. I added the `.replace` and it fixed my problem. Am assuming it's using regex. I've played with regex over the years, but not a lot, so I don't really understand the code. I DO understand that it fixes my problem! Thank you for your help.

Comment: well it's pretty simple. In `/'/g`  the slashes delimit the actual regex (just match apostrophe literally) and after that the extra **g** lobal flag is specified which means all apostrophes in the string will be replaced and not just the first one. The second argument is what to replace with, in this case it's `\'`. The extra backslash is to escape the backslash.